# how to use redux useSelector to check state and do a fetch to a database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, redux

I am using redux in a project and I want to make a  useSelector that  would check to see if the values in the redux state are the default values if not it will do a request to the database and update the  the state I feel like it is quite complicated though and I am having a hard time getting my head around how I need to do this.
I need to do this because sometimes the  correct state is not loaded in the  state I am considering just  doing a check  every time I use useSelector  to check if the values are the default values  then fetch from the database but I would much prefer to write  it a way that would allow to be handled within the redux selector but I can't really grasp I how I need to do it.

```
 const info =  useSelector(getInfo)
```

Ideally I would like the info to be handled when I fetch here

```
import { SET_USER_DETAILS } from "../constants/userConstants";

const intialState = {
  user: { },
};

const userReducer = (state = intialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER_DETAILS:
      return { ...state, user: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

here is what my current reducer looks like what would be the best way to do this as I am finding it a little bit difficult to follow the documentation on the  redux website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use redux-thunk. https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks
then your thunk could look something like that:

```
const thunkFunction = (dispatch, getState) => {
  // logic here that can dispatch actions or read state

  const currentState = getState() as typeof initialState;
  // check if state is default state
  if (JSON.stringify(initialState) === JSON.stringify(currentState)) {
    fetch(url).then(data => {
      dispatch({type: SET_USER_DETAILS, payload: data})
    })
  }
}
```

You need first to fetch data in react component:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  // while fetch is fetching, data will be default state,
  // and when fetch is done, that component will automatically
  // rerender with new data
  
  const data = useSelector(getInfo);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(thunkFunction)
  },[])
  return <code>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>
}
```

I did not test it so may require some changes
but in general concept is like this

Comment: Thank you for the doucmentation i didnt see that part of it before I want to take the logic out of UI layer so this isn't quite what I was looking for  a way to write the method and everything would be handled with the one function by creating a custom selector

Comment: Ok. You can also use `reselect` library for it.